# Flutter How to know Workmanager has finished

Tags: flutter, flutter-workmanager

I use Flutter with the plugin [Workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager). I did not find a way to know if the background task has finished for [registerOneOffTask](https://pub.dev/documentation/workmanager/latest/workmanager/%E2%80%A6). I had ideas with [RxSharedPreferences](https://github.com/hoc081098/rx_shared_preferences) that I write something from the Workmanager into SharedPreferences and then observe it in my main application but this seems to be quite dirty.

Is there an elegant way to know if the Workmanager task is finished?

Comment: you use this https://pub.dev/documentation/workmanager/latest/workmanager/Workmanager/registerOneOffTask.html?

Comment: Yes, I add it to my description.

Comment: so it returns s `Future` - I guess it completes when task is done

Comment: No, it does return, when the task is registered. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Before you're `executeTask` is about to finish, you can write the result to `SharedPreferences`  using the task's unique name you will provide.

While the tasks are running, run a 1 second timeout to check the running tasks' result change by observing their `SharedPreferences`  keys. Once a value of a key changes, remove the entry from `SharedPreferences` , and handle the result as needed.